# Only show single array of objects from Rest api in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to only show a single array item from a rest api i.e. Home array with title object in my React app. But my current code shows the element twice, is it because I am mapping through them on Render?

Code so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React', 
      awsApiData: [],
    };
  }

 componentDidMount() {
        console.log('app mounted');
        fetch('https://onelbip0e6.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/livestage/data')
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({awsApiData: data}, () => console.log(data)))
    }

  render() {
    const data = this.state.awsApiData;
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(data).map(e => {
          return <div>{data.home[0].title}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**api schema**

```
{
  "home": [
    {
      "title": "John Doe title",
      "body": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.",
      "image": "image/example.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "about": [
    {
      "title": "John is the main part 1",
      "body": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.",
      "image": "image/example.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: how many keys are printed in `Object.keys`? and whats the shape of API response

Comment: I have updated the question with the api schema, in this case its 2

Comment: Yes as your response has 2 keys, `map` loops twice. Be advised to use `key` parameter on child elements inside `map`.

Comment: do you have a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response of the API that you are calling `https://onelbip0e6.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/livestage/data` is as follows:

```
{
  "home": [
    {
      "title": "John Doe title",
      "body": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.",
      "image": "image/example.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "about": [
    {
      "title": "John is the main part 1",
      "body": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.",
      "image": "image/example.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can modify your render method by just removing the Object.keys() and map from it and it will be fixed,

```
render() {
    const data = this.state.awsApiData;
    return (
      <div>
          {(data && data.home) &&
              <div>{data.home[0].title}</div>
          }    
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I know it can be done like that, but want to know how to access it only in the render method

Comment: That did not work gives error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Yes, there should be a condition for the first time when awsApiData variable is empty data. Please check now.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not display anything